# How to have a different "placeholder style" and at the same time a different "text-input style" in Rails with CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a weird selector issue the  "input[type="text"]" selector overrides the "::placeholder" selector. Even though the "::placeholder" selector comes after the "input[type="text"]" selector.

**Questions:**

Why is this happening?

And how can I achieve different styles for the input text and placeholder text at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority of css rules is not just based on the order in which they appear:  more specific rules win over less specific.  Eg, in this case

```
div.bar div.foo { background: blue;}
div.foo { background: red;}
```

the first rule will "win" because it's more specific.  I suspect that the `::placeholder` is winning over `input[type="text"]` for this reason - that it's deemed (by the browser) to be more specific.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm

Comment: Thanks the "::placeholder" inherit the style "text-transform: uppercase;" from the  "input[type="text"]" I was able to solve that!